# Defining class relations in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django/Python, so excuse me if my question is straightforwardly obvious!

I am trying to create a User class, and each user will have the option to select (one or more) sports disciplines as his hobbies.

So far I defined all the sports activities in a class called Hobbies:

```
class Hobbies(models.Model):
    sports_name = models.IntegerField()
```

and the user class:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,blank=True)
```

I have no idea how to proceed as I have no prior experience with django/Python.

I need to create a sort of array in my user class where I would store all the hobbies a certain user "registers" for.

Comment: Minor note: You'll probably want to call "Hobbies" "Hobby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a many-to-many field to your profile model, which enables you to create a relationship between users and hobbies:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
  gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
  hobbies = models.ManyToManyField(Hobbies)
```

You can then get a list of a users hobbies by doing a related lookup:

```
user = Profile.objects.get(pk=1)
hobbies = user.hobbies.all()
```

More info: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield

Comment: do we need to use all() or can we just use hobbies = user.hobbies_set ?

Comment: `hobbies_set` is a manager instance that behaves in the same way as `objects`. You need to call a queryset method to return results - you have access to all the standard queryset methods: all, filter, get, etc. You can read more about how relationships are handled here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/relations/

Comment: I think I get part of the idea. If I understand correct, this statement should return all of the user's hobbies. When I try to run `hobbies = user.hobbies_set.all()` I get `'Profile' object has no attribute 'hobbies_set'`... . Another question :) If I need to add a hobby for a user, what would the syntax be?

Comment: Side note: if you add a field to your model, you need to make sure that the relevant field is added to the database. This will differ depending on the database engine you are using, but you should be able to run python manage.py reset <app_name> from your project root to update this. You can add a hobby by creating an instance of your `Hobbies` model, and then using user.hobbies_set.add(hobby)

Comment: @Sam - unfortunately Gary's answer was not quite accurate. To get the hobbies for a user, just do `hobbies = user.hobbies.all()`. The `_set` comes in when you want to get _users_ for a _hobby_: you do `users = hobby.user_set.all()`.

Comment: @Daniel - you're quite right. Apologies for any confusion; long day :S

Answer (score 0):

Question indicates that you hadn't any experience with relational databases at all. As Django models maps (almost) directly to underlying db relations, I would suggest diving into some database (framework- and language-agnostic) tutorial//book.

For that, check [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983336/relational-database-theory-and-sql-book-recommendations). Then pick one of the RDBMS (PostgreSQL is fine, opensource, free) and experiment a little, then go back to Django.

Comment: no I don't have experience with relational databases. Any suggestion on a good tutorial/book?

Comment: thanks a lot !! this will definitely help me grasp the concepts I am missing!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a M2M relation to me. Here is how to do this:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships